How to open Android's built-in HTML Viewer from the command line?
For example, I am able to open the Android Settings app from Termux using the following code'
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.Settings

Is there a way to open Android's built-in HTML Viewer from Termux that same way?

This question is similar to: Need command line to start web browser using adb. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
